# The use of swift macros prevents the execution of other code

Tags: ios, swift, macros, expand, freestanding

I created a `unwrap` freestanding macro that unwraps optional values.
[image]
The implementation looks like the following code:

```swift
{ [\(raw: argumentName)] in
    guard let \(raw: argumentName) else {
        preconditionFailure("Unexpectedly found nil")
    }
    return \(raw: argumentName)
}()
```

When applied to actual code, it expands as shown below:

[image]

Secondly, I created a `unwrapNotEmpty` macro that unwraps an optional value and checks whether it's empty:
[image]

```swift
{ [\(raw: argumentName)] in
    let unwrapValue = #unwrap(\(raw: argumentName))
    guard !unwrapValue.isEmpty else {
        preconditionFailure("Unexpectedly found empty")
    }
    return unwrapValue
}()
```

The expansion looks like this:

[image: ![image-20240224185538944](/Users/sujikang/Library/Application Support/typora-user-images/image-20240224185538944.png)]

I expected a failure in the `unwrapNotEmpty` macro when I created an empty string called "greeting" and executed each macro:

```swift
let greeting: String? = ""
let unwrap = #unwrap(greeting)
let unwrapNotEmpty = #unwrapNotEmpty(greeting)

print("unwrap: \(unwrap)")
print("unwrapNotEmpty: \(unwrapNotEmpty)")
```

However, in reality, both print statements at the bottom executed without errors:

```swift
unwrap: 
unwrapNotEmpty:
```

When I commented out the execution of the `#unwrap` macro, the failure in the `unwrapNotEmpty` macro was triggered.

I suspected an issue when macros are executed consecutively. To investigate, I tried using only the `unwrap` macro without the `unwrapNotEmpty` macro, keeping the expanded form as it is:

```swift
let greeting: String? = ""
let unwrap = #unwrap(greeting)
let unwrapNotEmpty = { [greeting] in
    let unwrapValue = { [greeting] in
        guard let greeting else {
            preconditionFailure("Unexpectedly found nil")
        }
        return greeting
    }()
    guard !unwrapValue.isEmpty else {
        preconditionFailure("Unexpectedly found empty")
    }
    return unwrapValue
}()

print("unwrap: \(unwrap)")
print("unwrapNotEmpty: \(unwrapNotEmpty)")
```

However, even in this case, both print statements at the bottom executed without errors:

```swift
unwrap: 
unwrapNotEmpty:
```

I also tried the opposite, where I kept the `unwrap` macro in its expanded form and used only the `unwrapNotEmpty` macro:

```swift
let greeting: String? = ""
let unwrap = { [greeting] in
    guard let greeting else {
        preconditionFailure("Unexpectedly found nil")
    }
    return greeting
}()
let unwrapNotEmpty = #unwrapNotEmpty(greeting)

print("unwrap: \(unwrap)")
print("unwrapNotEmpty: \(unwrapNotEmpty)")
```

Still, in this case, both print statements at the bottom executed without errors:

```swift
unwrap: 
unwrapNotEmpty:
```

When I wrote both macros in their expanded forms, the `Unexpectedly found empty` error was triggered as expected:

```swift
let unwrap = { [greeting] in
    guard let greeting else {
        preconditionFailure("Unexpectedly found nil")
    }
    return greeting
}()
let unwrapNotEmpty = { [greeting] in
    let unwrapValue = { [greeting] in
        guard let greeting else {
            preconditionFailure("Unexpectedly found nil")
        }
        return greeting
    }()
    guard !unwrapValue.isEmpty else {
        preconditionFailure("Unexpectedly found empty")
    }
    return unwrapValue
}()

print("unwrap: \(unwrap)")
print("unwrapNotEmpty: \(unwrapNotEmpty)")
```

I also created a `notEmpty` macro that checks if the value is not empty and returns it:
[image]

```swift
{ [\(raw: argumentName)] in
    guard let \(raw: argumentName), !\(raw: argumentName).isEmpty else {
        return nil
    }
    return \(raw: argumentName)
}()
```

[image]

Then, I removed the `unwrap` macro and tried executing `unwrapNotEmpty` consecutively:

```swift
let greeting: String? = ""
let notEmpty = #notEmpty(greeting)
let unwrapNotEmpty = #unwrapNotEmpty(greeting)
print("notEmpty: \(notEmpty)")
print("unwrapNotEmpty: \(unwrapNotEmpty)")
```

This time, a failure was triggered in the `unwrapNotEmpty` macro:

[image]

So, I learned that the fact that two macros are executed consecutively doesn't mean a specific code won't work.

Under what circumstances does the use of macros prevent the execution of other code?

Comment: Can you show how you have declared the macros? I mean the `public macro unwrap(...) = #externalMacro(...)` declaration.

Comment: @Sweeper 
I have it as follows. Other macro declaration also attached in the main text

`@freestanding(expression)
public macro unwrap<Wrapped>(_ expr: Wrapped?) -> Wrapped = #externalMacro(module: "MacroMacros", type: "UnwrapMacro")`

Comment: This seems to only happen in the global scope. If I put the code into a function, I can no longer reproduce this. I'd suspect it's a compiler bug.

Comment: @Sweeper As you mentioned, if I put my usage of macro into a function, it works as I expected. (Xcode again...? ) Thank you for sharing.